# como desabilitar o botão de logar quando ocorrer o envio do formulário para o usuário não fazer varias requisições?

Tags: html

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para que o botão de logar seja desabilitado quando é feito o envio do formulário, para que o usuário não fique clicando varias vezes e enviando varias requisições.

Desde de já agradeço.

Comment: verifica se o login/cadastro teve sucesso, se tiver, seleciona o formulario, e o elemento filho(botao de envio) e atribui DISABLED nele

Comment: Se entendi bem, é só desabilitar o botão quando o mesmo for clicado. Não sei se você está usando o `$('form').submit()` ou usando AJAX, mas você pode desabilitar no retorno do submit, se necessário.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz uma modificação do exemplo do site: [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```js
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
        console.log('desabilita');
        $("#botao").prop("disabled", true);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
 <input type="text" value="Hello there">
 <input id="botao" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
 Trigger the handler
</div>
```

Comment: eu quero que o botão fique desabilitado apenas quando o formulário for enviado com sucesso, enquanto o formulário estiver faltando alguma coisa, o botão continua habilita.

Comment: @marcelovictor a lógica da resposta continua a mesma, basta adicionar o bloqueio após o envio. Entretanto, você não forneceu nenhum código, fica difícil fornecer uma resposta precisa com informações faltando.

Comment: @marcelovictor poste seu código :)

Answer (score 1):

Usando o examplo em cima, só tens que ver se o formulario é valido

```
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
        console.log('desabilita');
if ($("#myform").valid()) {
        $("#botao").prop("disabled", true);
}
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>

      $('#btnSalvar').on('click', function (e) {
            var button = $('#btnSalvar');

            button.prop('disabled', true);

            var valid = $("#MyForm").valid();
            console.log(valid);
            if (!valid) {

                e.preventDefault();
                button.prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('#MyForm').submit();
            }
        });
 </script> 
<style>

 button:disabled {
    background: red;
}
.invalid {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
 </style>

<form id="MyForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="" data-required-message="Name is required." class="valid">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="" data-required-message="Email is required." data-type-message="You must provide a valid email address." class="valid"><label for="email" generated="true" class="error" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid email address.</label>
    </div>
    <div>
       <button id="btnSalvar">Salvar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```